# Align text with columns

Tags: zurb-foundation

I want to display the text box for phone number in the following format
    (555)-555-5555.
    Whenever I try to add  the dashes or bracket they do not align correctly.
    How can I achieve this?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vahi/Sbt75/478/)

Code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large-2 columns">
    <label class="inline right">* Phone:</label>
</div>
<div class="large-3 columns">
    <span>(</span>
    <input type="text" id="areaCode" name="areaCodeTab" maxlength="3" />
    <span>)</span> -
</div>
<div class="large-3 columns">
    <input type="text" id="phoneMiddle" name="phoneMiddleTab" maxlength="3" /> -
</div>
<div class="large-3 columns end">
    <input type="text" id="phoneYearTab" name="phoneYearTab" maxlength="4" />
</div>
```

Comment: You want them all in one line? I'm not quite sure what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="row"> 
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <label class="inline right">* Phone:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <span class="prefix"> ( </span>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <input type="text" id="areaCode" name="areaCodeTab" maxlength="3" />
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <span class="postfix"> ) - </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <input type="text" id="phoneMiddle" name="phoneMiddleTab" maxlength="3" /> -
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns end">
        <input type="text" id="phoneYearTab" name="phoneYearTab" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

I think this is right, you may want to change the sizes of things but it all fit's together the way I think you're after.

## EDIT

Like this then?

```
<div class="row"> 
<div class="large-3 columns">
    <label class="inline right">* Phone:</label>
</div>
<div class="large-3 columns">
    <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <p class="">(</p>
        </div>
        <div class="large-10 columns">
            <input type="text" id="areaCode" name="areaCodeTab" maxlength="3" />
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <p class="">)-</p>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="large-3 columns">
    <input type="text" id="phoneMiddle" name="phoneMiddleTab" maxlength="3" /> -
</div>
<div class="large-3 columns end">
    <input type="text" id="phoneYearTab" name="phoneYearTab" maxlength="4" />
</div>
</div>
```

Can't help but think it looks better with the post and pre fix though.

Comment: I dont want the brackets or hyphens as a prefix or postfix.

Comment: Edited post to reflect that -